# how does the computer compare the hexadecimal and decimal values

Tags: c

I was looking through an existing code in C wherein there is a check for no's in a particular range 100 to 899. I wanted to add one more condition along with that the no can have the value 1FE. I should not convert it to a decimal no. But I need to check for this hexadecimal value.
    My doubt here is, How will the hardware interpret the comparision of the decimal and the hexadecimal. The hardware will interpret the values in zero's and one's. So will it convert the decimal and hexadecimal no's to binary to check the value ? (As 1FE when converted to decimal is 510 which will be included within the no 899).Please help to understand.

Comment: Why so much "no"? Be positive, and good things will come to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int x = 0x1fe;` and `int x = 510;` are the exact same thing to the computer (or more specifically, to the compiler -- the actual hardware will never see "0x1fe" or "510" -- it will only see the binary version) so your question doesn't make much sense.

Changing the base only changes the representation of a value; it doesn't change the actual value.  If you have 101<sub>2</sub> apples, and you have 5<sub>10</sub> apples, you still have the same amount of apples.

The representation computers use just happens to be binary.  (Well, doesn't 'just happen' to be, but.... yeah.)

Comment: I'm parsing the hexadecimal values and converting it into decimal for user understanding(eg. 100-899(binary) is 64-393(in hex)).I should not convert the hex no 1FE  and should check for this value. I now think if computer takes the binary representation of these values. will there be redundancy in the code as the no 1FE comes within the 100 to 899 range and i'm doing a separate check for 1FE and for the page numbers in the range 100-899.

Comment: If you don't want 1FE to be converted, then just check if the input is the string `"1FE"`.  How you would actually do this depends on your code.

Answer (score 3):

> My doubt here is, How will the hardware interpret the comparision of the decimal and the hexadecimal.

The hardware has no notion of decimal or hexadecimal. To the machine 0x1FE and 510 are indistinguishable; they are simply two different representations of exactly the same thing.